# MiniBufExpl: List buffers by window

Tags: buffers, vim-windows

Is there anyway to get MiniBufExpl to only list the buffers that belongs to the active window?

Comment: By "active window", you most probably mean "active tab". A window, in Vim, can show exactly one buffer at any one time.

Comment: @VanLaser: No, I mean active window. Too bad it can't do that.

Comment: Your question had no sense, then.

Comment: @VanLaser: No I mean the active window, not the active buffer. If I have two windows in one tab (workspace). I want to only see the buffers that exists in the window that's active.

Comment: Yes, and that doesn't make any sense - since a window has no memory, only a current, displaying, associated buffer.

Comment: How would I know that? I'm just an end-user.

Comment: By reading about windows, buffers and tabs ;) You can have a list of buffers for the current tab, though: http://vi.stackexchange.com/a/4231/1800

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. **Buffers are global, they don't belong to any specific window.**
2. If you didn't find a positive answer in the plugin's documentation, the answer is very likely to be negative.