# How can I prevent some buffers from being reachable using bnext, bprev?

Tags: buffers, terminal-buffer

I'm using a combination of buffers and splits. What I want is for `:bnext` or `:bprev` (or some equivalent) not to open buffers that are already opened in some other split or tab.

Is this possible?

Comment: I think your question is a duplicate of [this question](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/4091/1841) I asked a few years ago. Note that I didn't find any satisfying answer and then realized that the problem came from my workflow and not the possiblity to skip a buffer :)

Comment: It reads like a duplicate to me, too. And there's some great answers on the linked question!

Comment: `set nobuflisted`

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative, stop using `:bnext` / `:bprev` for navigation.

["Why ride a bike when you can fly?"](http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-d1GaUBk-Y10/TyFhskmCYRI/AAAAAAAAARQ/CIEx1V7FLqg/s640/vim-and-vigor-004-flying_is_faster_than_cycling.png)

Just open the buffer you want where you want to open it (and how).

#### Behold the power of `:b`!:

- Uses `<tab>` completion
- Use `<c-d>` to list out completion
- Use partial file name. e.g. `:b foo`. Works great with `<tab>`.
- Globbing. e.g. `:b foo*bar` or `:b foo/**/bar`
- Split variant of `:b` is `:sb`.
- Also accepts a buffer number
- A common mapping: `nnoremap <leader>b :ls<cr>:b<space>`

Using `:b` / `:sb` will allow you to simply open the buffer you want. No more cycling. No more worrying about the buffer list (`:set hidden`). This often leads to simpler window layouts, because you do not feel like you need to "store" a buffer in some split because it is tedious to find it again.

Comment: Actually i just have a buffer on right side which is mostly terminal and have like 2-3 hidden buffers. So while my terminal is there i just use <tab> <s-tab> bindings to quickly go back and forth with the keys if i hape a lot of buffers i mostly use ctrlp in buffer mode

Comment: LOL you anwer to "how can I ride my bicycle this way" is don't ride a bicycle, ride a motorcycle instead.