# Switching buffers in VI while skipping any terminal in VI 8.1

Tags: buffers, terminal, terminal-buffer

I am using multiple files within the same tab and when I switch buffers using :bn I reach the terminal, at which point I have to issue the command again to move.
Here is the catch, I am using keymaps to do buffer switching instead of typing the entire command.

is there a way to skip the terminal buffer and move on with this keymap.

The possible solution I can think as of now is using a separate tab for the terminal while keeping the present one for code. this is not a huge deal, just keeping my laziness alive.

Any and all ideas are appreciated.

Comment: I don't think your suggested workaround will work. Having the terminal buffer open in a tab won't prevent `:bn` from opening it in another tab.

Comment: Have you thought about jumping to the exact buffer instead of cycling? You can use `:b partial<tab>` to go directly where you want to go. Related question: [How can I prevent some buffers from being reachable using bnext, bprev?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/14233/778)

Comment: from what I know, tabs are the group of windows and windows display buffers, I was not aware that buffers can move across tabs. If that is is the case then I might have to rethink my approach. as of now, I am using the full command, will try the answers provided too.

Answer (score 6):

This should work too:

```
augroup termIgnore
    autocmd!
    autocmd TerminalOpen * set nobuflisted
augroup END
```

Comment: You actually posted yours 9s before mine!

Comment: Stack exchange magic ^^

Comment: Haha! Anyhow, good solution. +1

Answer (score 3):

This should do the job:

```
function! BnSkipTerm()
  let start_buffer = bufnr('%')
  bn
  while &buftype ==# 'terminal' && bufnr('%') != start_buffer
    bn
  endwhile
endfunction

nnoremap <leader>bn :call BnSkipTerm()<CR>
```

It just keeps invoking `:bn` until it's not in a terminal window, by checking the `'buftype'` setting.

Comment: What happens if a terminal is the last buffer? Does this abort if the bn fails, or might it get stuck in the loop?

Comment: *ahem*. Fixed. :)

Answer (score 2):

Based on @Rich's answer, this is an extended version which ignores all special buffers (like the quickfix window), also takes a count to skip buffers and preserves the alternate buffer:

```
function! s:bswitch_normal(count, direction)
    " This function switches to the previous or next normal buffer excluding
    " all special buffers like quickfix or terminals
    " Modified version of https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/16710/37509
    let l:count = a:count
    let l:cmd = (a:direction ==# 'previous') ? 'bprevious' : 'bnext'
    let l:start_buffer = bufnr('%')
    while 1
        execute 'keepalt ' . l:cmd
        if &buftype == ''
            let l:count -= 1
            if l:count <= 0
                break
            endif
        endif
        " Prevent infinite loops if no buffer is a normal buffer
        if bufnr('%') == l:start_buffer && l:count == a:count
            break
        endif
    endwhile
    if bufnr('%') != l:start_buffer
        " Jump back to the start buffer once to set the alternate buffer
        execute 'buffer ' . l:start_buffer
        buffer #
    endif
endfunction

" Taken from `:help SID`
function! s:SID()
    return matchstr(expand('<SID>'), '<SNR>\zs\d\+\ze_')
endfunction

nnoremap <silent> <leader>bp :<C-u>execute 'call <SNR>' . <SID>SID() . '_bswitch_normal(' . v:count1 . ', "previous")'<CR>
nnoremap <silent> <leader>bn :<C-u>execute 'call <SNR>' . <SID>SID() . '_bswitch_normal(' . v:count1 . ', "next")'<CR>
```

The function `s:bswitch_normal` can be further improved by avoiding buffer switching (which can be slow on large files):

```
function! s:bswitch_normal(count, direction)
    " This function switches to the previous or next normal buffer excluding
    " all special buffers like quickfix or terminals
    let l:normal_buffers = filter(
                \ range(1, bufnr('$')),
                \ 'buflisted(v:val) && getbufvar(v:val, "&buftype") == ""'
                \ )
    if a:direction ==# 'previous'
        call reverse(l:normal_buffers)
    endif
    let l:next_buffer_index = 0
    " while
    "   `l:next_buffer_index` is not out of range and
    "   direction is 'next'      =>  buffer number <= active buffer number and
    "   direction is 'previous'  =>  buffer number >= active buffer number
    " `a => b` is expressed with `!a || b`
    while l:next_buffer_index < len(l:normal_buffers) &&
                \ (a:direction ==# 'previous' || l:normal_buffers[l:next_buffer_index] <= bufnr('%')) &&
                \ (a:direction !=# 'previous' || l:normal_buffers[l:next_buffer_index] >= bufnr('%'))
        let l:next_buffer_index += 1
    endwhile
    let l:next_buffer_index = (l:next_buffer_index + a:count - 1) % len(l:normal_buffers)
    execute 'buffer ' . l:normal_buffers[l:next_buffer_index]
endfunction
```

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Comment: Didn't see this answer when you posted it. Great stuff! +1