# Skip the quickfix list when buffer switching using :bn

Tags: vimrc, buffers, quickfix

Often when editing LaTeX files, you are constantly switching between your `.tex`, `.sty` and `.bib` files which are often in their own buffer.

To navigate between those, I use the `:bn` and `:bp` commands which I have remapped to `<Tab>` and `<S-Tab>` for convenience.

Yet, vimtex by default enables the quickfix buffer.

How can I skip the quickfix buffer when buffer switching (the buffers are not in split windows)?

Comment: Why not create dedicated local mappings for tex files? Is there a way to reliably predict the names of some of the files, or otherwise prepopulate a list of choices? Have you considered using `args` and `argnext` instead?

Comment: Ben's suggestion is pretty good I think you are facing what they call an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/288754). To add to his suggestion I think you could have a look at [vim-projectionist](https://github.com/tpope/vim-projectionist): If I'm not mistaken it allows you to define different alternate files which could be useful here (but I never used it and I'm not 100% sure this is what you need)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can adapt [either of the answers here](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/16708/switching-buffers-in-vi-while-skipping-any-terminal-in-vi-8-1) to skip the quickfix:

Here's my one:

```
function! BSkipQuickFix(command)
  let start_buffer = bufnr('%')
  execute a:command
  while &buftype ==# 'quickfix' && bufnr('%') != start_buffer
    execute a:command
  endwhile
endfunction

nnoremap <Tab> :call BSkipQuickFix("bn")<CR>
nnoremap <S-Tab> :call BSkipQuickFix("bp")<CR>
```