# How to pin a file to a window(/viewport)

Tags: buffers, vim-windows, split, multiple-files

When I have multiple files open in multiple splits, when I open a new file via quickfix ( or Ctrl-P ), it sometimes ends up placing the new file in a window that I don't want to be changed.

Is there a way we can specify a lock/pin on the viewport so that new files don't replace them?

Comment: I think your question is more or less the same problem I had [a few years ago](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/4091/1841) and I think the answer to this question is: it's not really possible to enforce what you want to do without being extremely hacky.